# How to unsubscribe from Observable if there is no object of type "Subscription"?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscription

If I subscribe to an Observable, how can I unsubscribe from it, if there is no object of type "Subscription"?

If I have something like:

```
this.subscription = bla ...
```

then I can unsubscribe from it as follows (in the ngOnDestroy()-method):

```
this.subscription.unsubscribe();
```

But what if I have something like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {

    this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn();

    this.isLoggedIn$.subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
      } 
      else {
        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      }
    });

  }
```

How can I unsubscribe from this?  Do I even have to unsubscribe? If not, why not?

Comment: Here is some documentation on [Angular Observables](https://angular.io/guide/observables) which the subscribe method is working with. As far as whether or not you have to unsubscribe, it's hard to say without knowing more about what you're wanting to do. Perhaps the docs could provide some insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 methods to unsubscribe an observable

1. You can use above approach as `this.subscription` to assign subscribe
   for every subscribe and then unsubscribe each every explicitly. (It
   should be avoided)
2. You can use takWhile pipe by using the example
   below:

   ```
   private isAlive = true;

   ngOnInit() {

     this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn();

     this.subscription = this.isLoggedIn$
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
      .subscribe(res => {
       if (res) {
         this.isLoggedIn = true;
       } 
       else {
         this.isLoggedIn = false;
       }
     });

   }


   ngOnDestroy() {
      console.log('[takeWhile] ngOnDestory');
      this.alive = false;
   }
   ```
3. Use takeUntil operator:

   ```
   private unsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject();

   ngOnInit() {

     this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn();

     this.subscription = this.isLoggedIn$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe(res => {
       if (res) {
         this.isLoggedIn = true;
       } 
       else {
         this.isLoggedIn = false;
       }
     });
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
     this.unsubscribe.next();
     this.unsubscribe.complete();
   }
   ```

I Hope This helped!!

Answer (score 2):

You have actually provided your own answer here: `bla ...` is your `this.isLoggedIn$.subscribe( ... )` call.

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn();

  this.subscription = this.isLoggedIn$.subscribe(res => {
    if (res) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
    } 
    else {
      this.isLoggedIn = false;
    }
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if this.isLoggedIn$ exists before unsubscribe

```
ngOnDestroy() {
this.isLoggedIn$ && this.isLoggedIn$.unsubscribe();
}
```